# random number generator dev/random

Tags: macos, random, solaris, numbers, generator

I read that the random number generator dev/random on Mac and Solaris includes 160 bits of entropy. What can I do, if I need more entropy, for example, 200 bits? Thanks in advance

Comment: Upgrade to Linux. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you read that 160-bit estimate -- I believe that Solaris, Mac and most BSDs use a 256-bit Yarrow implementation.  At any rate, the entropy pool is regularly refilled from even the smallest amount of network or disk activity, so, even though `/dev/random` on non-Linux systems doesn't actually *block* "waiting for more entropy" (it's more like a supposedly higher-quality version of `/dev/urandom`, to which on these systems it's typically linked), nothing stops you (if you trust, say, no more than 160 bits at a time from the `/dev`) from "blocking and refreshing entropy" yourself -- get N bits, do some disk or network I/O, get another N bits, and so forth.

Comment: Not sufficient, see https://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg00620.html

Answer (score -1):

And if you think your disk access is too predictable, you could go for some really bizzare sources like, say, a few of the most recent twitter entries if your program has internet access;)

Comment: It's too predictable. You can approximate the entropy generation time, and brute-force with Twitter data from that time. Problem is similar to using time as entropy source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397017/1004787