# Is "srand(time(0) * int_value))" a good way to get different values for each execution?

Tags: c, random

I want to get random float values between 0 and 10 for each execution, and if i don't use **`srand(time(0))`, **my random values always same in each execution. However, if i use this, i get different values but it changes like 0.01 between two consecutive executions.

So my question is this:

If I use `srand(time(0) * 1000)`, I get different random numbers for each execution. Is this a proper way to use like this, or will there be an overflow because of seed limits or something like that for a specific times?

Here is a simple function to get different float values between 0 and 10

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(0) * 1000);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        float randomValue = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * 10;
        printf("Random float value %d: %.2f\n", i + 1, randomValue);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want "good" random numbers, `rand()` is a really poor choice. It's notoriously bad. Use `/dev/urandom` or equivalent if you can.

Comment: I've always seeded like this -- srand(time(NULL))  -- which has always been fine.  I'm curious about your 1000 multiplier -- did someone advise that?  Did they say why?

Comment: The convention is `srand(time(NULL))` but note that this produces the same results in any given second.

Comment: If you're using a Linux distro or openBSD, [`getentropy()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getentropy.3.html) is a good way to get a random seed.

Comment: (I'd also suggest a different rng; maybe [`drand48()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html) on unixy OSes or [PCG](https://www.pcg-random.org/)

Comment: It doesn't matter if you multiply the seed value with `time(0) * 1000`. It's just another seed with defined behaviour because the `unsigned` value will wrap.

Comment: ... pretty sure the answer to your question is "yes, that's fine, no issues."  But there are much better experts than I am here.   So I'll also be looking to see if and how someone answers, officially -- as an *answer.*

Comment: @gregspears if i use srand(time(NULL)), my numbers does not change enough between two consecutive executions(It changes 0.01 like this) and I tried to multiply so numbers change a lot better than this.

Comment: @Emirkan -- wow!  That *is* interesting.   OK, now I'm going to copy paste your code and run some tests.

Comment: It makes no difference what you muiltiply `time(0)` by: it still only changes once per second.

Comment: @WeatherVane I realised that only first element does not change enough with only time(0) but other elements change enough between consecutive executions.

Comment: `rand()` is typically (note: doesn't *have* to be but aside from OpenBSD likely is) implemented with a simple [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) where similar initial seeds result in similar sequences. But they're *different* sequences which is usually what you need.

Comment: Hi @Emirkan -- sorry, I am not seeing any significant difference when I toggle between the 2 types of srand() -- code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xevrs4Ya4).  Maybe you could experiment on the godbolt platform and see too.  This code is editable in the link.  Maybe something is up with your compiler?

Comment: @gregspears My first element changes only 0.01 each second, others are fine to me when i use time(0) only.

Comment: "_others are fine to me_" ... If the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and subsequent values satisfy your idea of randomness, simply add `(void) rand();` ahead of the loop to discard the 1st returned _random number_... KISS

Comment: @Fe2O3 I don't want to complicate my main code for getting random numbers, because it is not main idea of my homework(my main work is cuda right now). Multiplying also satisfy my idea but i didn't know that is it a proper way to use it, i just wanted to know whether it gives error in specific time.

Comment: Hi @Emirkan  -- [here is another](https://godbolt.org/z/4r3Mq5K48) variation to examine.  I am still seeing a lot of variation in the 1st element when I toggle between the two srand() methods.  *Very sorry* if this does not help, or I haven't understood.

Comment: "_don't want to complicate my main code_" Then don't. You've noticed a behaviour of your compiler's `rand()` that you want to avoid. Add the one trivial line of code suggested with a comment stating `// discarding first rand() value`. Done. Mucking with multiplying or taking the square root of `time()` to the power of Euler's number **is** complicating your code... KISS...

Comment: What OS? You can use process ID besides `time()` for random seed, i.e. `srand(getpid() + time(NULL))`. On many OSes you can use `getrandom()`.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand) is a very interesting and possibly related stackoverflow -- "Recommended way to initialize srand?"   On the bright side, your question is getting lots of support and attention -- congrats on that.

Comment: @dimich Wish you'd posted your suggestion as an answer. I'd UV it asap. Instead, not seeing your solution, I went ahead and posted the same thing about 20 minutes ago... Mine's gone now, so the floor is yours... at least one UV awaits...

Comment: Even though it is tagged C++, most of this question is relevant for C as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397004/better-seeds-than-time0

Comment: @Fe2O3 I wouldn't consider my comment as answer, it doesn't answer OP's direct question "Is srand(time(0)) a good way...".

Comment: If changing the seed by 1 consistently changes the first `rand()` result by 1, then there is something seriously wrong with the `rand()` implementation. I am sorry, but I am somewhat doubtful about this observation. I certainly cannot reproduce it. Try running with a few values `srand(0)`, `srand(1)`, `srand(2)`, ...

Answer (score 3):

> If I use srand(time(0) * 1000), I get different random numbers for each execution. Is this a proper way to use like this, or will there be an overflow because of seed limits or something like that for a specific times?

`srand(time(0) * 1000)` is weaker than `srand(time(0))` for the following reason.

`time()` typical returns an integer.  Scaling by 1000 (same as 5<sup>3</sup> * 2<sup>3</sup>) results in a product whose 3 least significant bits are 0.  Converting that product to `unsigned`, the type of the `void srand(unsigned int seed);` parameter retains those 3 least significant bits as 0.  The `unsigned seed` with its `n` bits (typically 32) now has `3` fewer "random" bits.

Scaling by a `prime > 2`, rather than 1000, may have merit. Hmmm.

---

> Is "srand(time(0) * int_value))" a good way to get different values for each execution?

A common alternative approach to initialize with `srand()` in a way that 2 programs starting in the same `time()` (e. g. same second) likely have a different seed involves using other "random" sources.

Whatever sources are used, better to `^` them together using *unsigned* math rather than `|, &, *, /, ...`.

Some systems provide a process ID.

```
#include <unistd.h>

...
pid_t pid = getpid();
// `time_t` may be a floating point type.  Convert to an integer to allow `^`
unsigned long long t = (unsigned long long) time(0);
srand(t ^ pid);
```

Another useful source, if true user input occurs before `srand()` is to query `clock()`.

[@selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie) offers a useful idea of taking the address of a variable.  That address may be fixed or differ per program run.  Exclusively or-ing it in would cause no harm, yet may provide more "random" bits.

- Deeper:  When mixing various "random" bits together, consider spreading the random bits out.  Time bits tend to have common MSbits and different LSbits.  Time and PID tend to both increment.  Addresses tend to have the most different bits a few bits above the LSbits.  See [Recommended way to initialize srand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322938/2410359) for a C++ approach.  It has some relevance for C.

---

Of course various systems offer superior random number functions than `srand(), rand()`.

---

[Edit 20204]

[@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77405408/is-srandtime0-int-value-a-good-way-to-get-different-values-for-each-exe/77405912#comment136468050_77405548) brings up a good point about weak `rand()` sequences given one started with `srand(t)` and another with `srand(t + 1)`: the generated *random values* do not certainly quickly diverge.

Rather than scale by 1000, which has the above mentioned problem, scale by a not-too-small *prime* to separate consecutive time samples.

```
srand(time(0) * 251u);
```

Scaling by a prime > 2 does not harm good `srand()/rand()` implementations (unless that *prime* is the `c` in `(a•x[i]+b) % c`), yet can help weak ones.

Ultimately, the quality of `srand()/rand()` in a given implementation is not specified by C and so may have many weaknesses.  A robust solution uses other random number generators.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying with a fixed number doesn't make the seed more random. If you start two programs at approximately the same time, you'll still get the same seed.

You could use a clock which probably has higher resolution to reduce the risk of getting the same seed:

```c
unsigned get_seed(void) {
    struct timespec ts;
    timespec_get(&ts, TIME_UTC);
    unsigned seed = (unsigned)(ts.tv_sec * 1000000000ull + ts.tv_nsec);
    // mix in other sources of semi-randomness into seed if needed
    return seed;
}

srand(get_seed());
```

Or use a source of true randomness to seed your PRNG. On linux you'll have `/dev/random` or the newer `getrandom()` from which you could read `sizeof(unsigned)` bytes to create your seed.

Comment: Re “Multiplying with a fixed number doesn't make the seed more random”: It can help mitigate an issue with OP’s bad `rand` implementation, which is that it has a low multiplier for its linear congruential generator.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't see how starting it off at a different point helps. If you start two programs at the same time, they will most likely get the same seed and therefore generate the same sequence.  Sidenote: In glibc, `rand` uses `__random_r` which has an `if (buf->rand_type == TYPE_0)` then they use the old LCG _" Otherwise, we do our fancy trinomial stuff"_. I wonder why they don't use the fancy one all the time? Is `rand` expected to generate the same sequences between releases and now they are stuck this the bad one?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: A linear congruential generator (LCG) has x[i+1] = (a•x[i]+b) % c. LCG are not entirely unsuitable for some simple needs, but OP is complaining that if they have two seeds, x[0] and y[0], that differ by 1, then x[1] and y[1] differ by only a. Note this is not a problem in a single LCG sequence; it is only a problem when you compare two LCG sequences with similar seeds. So it does not mean any particular LCG sequence is a problem for OP; they are just complaining the first number generated in each of two sequences with seeds close to each other are close…

Comment: … (This effect vanishes after a few repetitions of the generator, as the differences grow far enough apart that the wrapping modulo by m splits the paths of the two sequences.) So a mitigation for that is to spread the seeds apart. I would use something other than 1000 though; you would want some number relatively prime to m and largeish.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, is _that_ what _"However, if i use this, i get different values but it changes like 0.01 between two consecutive executions"_ means? Ok, then I get why the multiplication could help some. I'd still go for better source(s) though.  Using `timespec_get` is pretty much a drop-in replacement for `time(0)` if one puts it in `unsigned get_seed(void);` to hide the implementation -  and one can then add other sources to the function to create a better seed if needed later.

Answer (score 2):

`time` and `rand` are perfectly fine as a random number seed if you don't have a security issue with it.  Be advised that:

- time returns a value in seconds.  So if your program is started multiple times within the same second, it will use the same seed and hence, generate identical results.
- No point in multiplying `time(0)` by 1000 as you have in your example. Just time(0) or `time(NULL)`

Here's some code I wrote a long time ago to seed a random number generator. It's not necessarily secure or the best.  But it works for Windows, Linux, and Mac.

```
    uint32_t entropy=0;


    // on x86, the rdtsc instruction is about as good as it gets for a random sequence number
    // on linux, there's /dev/urandom


#ifdef _WIN32
    // on windows, there's lots of simple stuff we can get at to give us a random number
    // the rdtsc instruction is about as good as it gets
    uint64_t clock = __rdtsc();
    entropy ^= (uint32_t)(clock);
#else
    // on linux, /dev/urandom should be sufficient
    {
        int randomfile = ::open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
        if (randomfile >= 0)
        {
            int readret = read(randomfile, &entropy, sizeof(entropy));
            close(randomfile);
        }
    }


    // fallback on unix when /dev/urandom isn't available
    if (entropy == 0)
    {
        entropy ^= getpid();
        entropy ^= reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this); // FOR C code use the address of any local variable
        entropy ^= time(NULL);
    }

#endif

    srand(entropy);
```

Comment: Minor: Since `srand(unsigned)` takes an `unsigned`, it makes sense for `unsigned entropy=0;` rather than `uint32_t`.

Comment: Re “`time` and `rand` are perfectly fine as a random number seed” and “No point in multiplying `time(0)` by 1000 as you have in your example. Just time(0) or `time(NULL)`”: This does not address OP’s problem, that using `time(0)` as you suggest produces initial `rand` results that differ only slightly from second to second. They have a bad `rand` implementation, likely a linear congruential generator with a small multiplier. They need to mitigate that either by multiplying `time(0)` by something or otherwise modifying it or by using a different generator.

Comment: Re “time returns a value in seconds”: That is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @selbie, `entropy ^= (uintptr_t)(this)` is interesting.

Comment: @selbie: `if (entropy == 0)` does sacrifice one legitimate random value as 0 could be a random value.  Perhaps a different test?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a user response time into the PRNG seed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
    
int main(void) {
    printf("Press Enter to begin\n");
    getchar();
    
    unsigned seed = (unsigned)time(NULL) + (unsigned)clock();
    printf("seed = %u\n", seed);
    srand(seed);
    printf("rand=%u\n", rand());
    return 0;
}
```

If there is user interaction you can also use `clock()` to modify the value from `rand()`.

Comment: This does not address OP’s problem, that using `time(0)` produces initial `rand` results that differ only slightly from second to second. They have a bad `rand` implementation, likely a linear congruential generator with a small multiplier. They need to mitigate that either by multiplying `time(0)` by something or otherwise modifying it or by using a different generator. Getting `time(NULL)` after user responds to a prompt will change the time slightly, but that only changes the initial `rand` result slightly.

Comment: Adding `clock()` is essentially useless as it measures processor time, which should vary little regardless of how long it takes the user to respond.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am distracted by MSVC's non-standard `clock()` function, which measures wall time.

Answer (score 1):

`srand/rand` is known to be a bad random generator.
Whatever the problem is mainly because the first generated value is too tighly coupled with the seed. Look at these first random values (time(0), rand, RAND_MAX, the computed float):

```
1698920210 809398958 2147483647 0.376906
1698920242 809936782 2147483647 0.377156
1698920258 810205694 2147483647 0.377281
```

Difference is less than what you expect.
A small workaround is (for example) to get only some of the less significant digits:

```
srand(time(0));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int r = rand()%10000;
    float randomValue = ((float)r / 10000) * 10;
    printf("Random float value %d: %.2f\n", i + 1, randomValue);
}
```

You will then get something like:

```
Random float value 1: 1.62
Random float value 2: 1.93
Random float value 3: 9.02
Random float value 4: 2.82
Random float value 5: 5.38
Random float value 6: 8.86
Random float value 7: 0.76
Random float value 8: 8.42
Random float value 9: 2.24
Random float value 10: 8.71
```

then

```
Random float value 1: 0.29
Random float value 2: 3.16
Random float value 3: 6.03
Random float value 4: 9.83
Random float value 5: 1.78
Random float value 6: 8.02
Random float value 7: 3.79
Random float value 8: 6.96
Random float value 9: 8.49
Random float value 10: 4.01
```

Comment: Re “A small workaround is (for example) to get only some of the less significant digits”: This is a bad idea because OP’s observation suggests their `rand` implementation uses a linear congruential generator, and linear congruential generators are notorious for having low entropy in their low bits.